# Hyphenation with Polyglossia

Tags: hyphenation, polyglossia, hebrew

I'm working with a document in English and Hebrew (using `polyglossia`), and am trying to add hyphenation in Hebrew wherever a hyphen might be.  Based on other questions/answers on this site, I have tried to use `hyphenat` to replace all my hyphens in Hebrew that I would like to be hyphenatable with `\hyp{}`, but it refuses to hyphenate.  See the minimal example below.  Manually adding hyphenation rules for individual words is impractical, as I will will have thousands of words to input.  Is there a way of forcing LaTeX to allow hyphenation even on the Hebrew side whenever it sees `\hyp{}` (or even better, an arbitrary character, for example the Hebrew version of the hyphen, U+05BE ־)?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{polyglossia,hyphenat}

\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguages{hebrew}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Arial Unicode MS}

\newcommand{\h}[1]{\RL{\texthebrew{#1}\hfil}}
\newcommand{\hangparagentry}{\hangindent-0.5em \hangafter1 \leftskip 0.8em \parindent -0.5em}
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\entry}{ m o m }{\noindent\hangparagentry{\hspace{-.5em}\textbf{#1}\hspace{0.5cm}\hfill \h{#3\IfNoValueF{#2}{ \textenglish{\scriptsize{#2}}}}}\par}

\begin{document}

\flushright

\entry{earthquake meter earthquake meter earthquake meter}{דער ע֜רד\hyp{}צי֜טערניש\hyp{}מע֜סטער, \hyp{}ס}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I thought Hebrew is *not* hyphenated (except in newspapers). However, `\-` should work

Comment: @egreg it's actually in Yiddish, but all the code reads "hebrew", so I didn't feel like confusing things. Also, I need the hyphen (or better yet maqqaf) to be there regardless of the word being split over multiple lines or not, hence my use of \hyp.

Comment: You may try with `\newcommand\hyp{\discretionary{<maqqaf>}{}{}}` (where `<maqqaf>` is code to produce the glyph; sorry, but I know nothing about Hebrew or Yiddish). Leave a space after `\hyp`, not `{}`.

Comment: @egreg Doesn't seem to work.  I put `\newcommand\hyp{\discretionary{-}{}{-}}`, as I wanted a hyphen even if it doesn't break, but it still won't break. Perhaps hyphenation is turned off by default on hebrew text in polyglossia?

Comment: Remove `hyphenat`. Also `\hfill` in the definition of `\entry` is responsible for missing hyphenation: [this picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/l71Oc.png) shows what I get when I change it to a simple space

Comment: @egreg Great! That works! You should post that as an answer.  Any idea why `\hfill` was preventing hyphenation?

Comment: @egreg In traditional Yiddish printing hyphenation by syllables is used, *except* for the words that come from Hebrew and Aramaic which are left untouched. It would be interesting to see whether it is possible to write reliable hyphenation-pattern that take this into account. Magicker72's  approach will (cleverly!) at least take care of the longest compounds automatically as long as we don't have real Yiddish hyphenation.

Comment: @Florian That's an interesting problem, but probably it requires extensive research and development.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove `hyphenat`, to begin with. You could define `\hyp` to do `\discretionary{-}{}{}` if you want a discretionary hyphen, but this would be the same as using `\-`.

If you want a “breakable at” hyphen, just use a hyphen.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguages{hebrew}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Arial Unicode MS}

\newcommand{\h}[1]{\RL{\texthebrew{#1}\hfil}}
\newcommand{\hangparagentry}{\hangindent-0.5em \hangafter1 \leftskip 0.8em \parindent -0.5em}

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\entry}{ m o m }{%
  \noindent\hangparagentry{\hspace{-.5em}\textbf{#1}\hspace{0.5cm} %\hfill
  \h{\hspace{0pt}#3\IfNoValueF{#2}{ \textenglish{\scriptsize{#2}}}}}\par}

\begin{document}

\flushright

\entry{earthquake meter earthquake meter earthquake meter}{דער ע֜רד-צי֜טערניש-מע֜סטער, -ס}

\parbox{0pt}{\h{\hspace{0pt}דער ע֜רד-צי֜טערניש-מע֜סטער, -ס}}

\end{document}
```

The `\parbox` at the end is just for showing that hyphens are good line break points.

Note that I changed `\hfill` in the definition of `\entry` to a simple space. Using `\hfill` makes TeX into thinking that it's better not to hyphenate in order to get a better paragraph.

[image]

Comment: If I left it as \hfil, would I still prevent hyphenation? I would like to avoid undue spacing between words.

Comment: @magicker72 It depends on several factors; too much stretch available will make TeX prefer not hyphenating. Use `\hspace{2em plus 2em}` or so instead of `\hfill`.

Comment: I've just noticed that your solution has issues outside the `\entry` environment.  Specifically, see the edit to the question.

Comment: @magicker72 It shouldn't be an edit, but a new (follow up) question.

Comment: Thanks, rolled back and [asked as a new question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/275238/inconsistent-line-breaks-instead-of-hyphenation).

Comment: If you want the maqaf instead of the Latin hyphen, you can use `\hebrewfont[HyphenChar="5BE,Script=Hebrew]{YourFont}` and then replace the hyphens in your source by maqafs.