# Inconsistent line breaks instead of hyphenation

Tags: line-breaking, hyphenation, polyglossia

Working off of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/229601/hyphenation-with-polyglossia), I see that XeLaTeX is inconsistently applying hyphenation to my text.  As you can see in the MWE, in the paragraph before the `\entry`, hyphenation is not applied, yet in the same text after the `\entry`, it is.  I can't understand what about the `\entry` is changing this hyphenation.  To be clear, I would like hyphenation to always be applied.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguages{hebrew}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Arial Unicode MS}

\newcommand{\h}[1]{\RL{\texthebrew{#1}\hfil}}
\newcommand{\hangparagentry}{\hangindent-0.5em \hangafter1 \leftskip 0.8em \parindent -0.5em}

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\entry}{ m o m }{%
  \noindent\hangparagentry{\hspace{-.5em}\textbf{#1}\hspace{0.5cm} %\hfill
  \h{\hspace{0pt}#3\IfNoValueF{#2}{ \textenglish{\scriptsize{#2}}}}}\par}

\begin{document}

\flushright


\h{דער ע֜רד-צי֜טערניש-מע֜סטער, -ס דער ע֜רד-צי֜טערניש-מע֜סטער, -ס דער ע֜רד-צי֜טערניש-מע֜סטער, -ס דער ע֜רד-צי֜טערניש-מע֜סטער, -ס דער ע֜רד-צי֜טערניש-מע֜סטער, -ס דער ע֜רד-צי֜טערניש-מע֜סטער, -ס דער ע֜רד-צי֜טערניש-מע֜סטער, -ס דער ע֜רד-צי֜טערניש-מע֜סטער, -ס }

\entry{anything}{\textenglish{blah}}

\h{דער ע֜רד-צי֜טערניש-מע֜סטער, -ס דער ע֜רד-צי֜טערניש-מע֜סטער, -ס דער ע֜רד-צי֜טערניש-מע֜סטער, -ס דער ע֜רד-צי֜טערניש-מע֜סטער, -ס דער ע֜רד-צי֜טערניש-מע֜סטער, -ס דער ע֜רד-צי֜טערניש-מע֜סטער, -ס דער ע֜רד-צי֜טערניש-מע֜סטער, -ס דער ע֜רד-צי֜טערניש-מע֜סטער, -ס }

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\flushright` is not a command to be used on its own; you probably mean `\raggedleft`

Comment: @egreg Fair.  However, I don't want the left side to be ragged -- I want justified sides, but right-to-left.  See my comment on jarauh's answer below.

Answer (score 1):

In `\hangparagentry`, you do a lot of changes to the parameters of the paragraph.  These changes persist after the end of `\entry`.  To make these changes local, you can, for example, add additional curly braces:

```
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\entry}{ m o m }{{%
  \noindent\hangparagentry{\hspace{-.5em}\textbf{#1}\hspace{0.5cm} %\hfill
  \h{\hspace{0pt}#3\IfNoValueF{#2}{ \textenglish{\scriptsize{#2}}}}}}\par}
```

Basically, it is the command `\flushright` that prevents the hyphenation in the first place.  `\flushright` sets `\leftskip` to a flexible value that prevents hyphenations.

As egreg suggested in a comment to [another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/229601/hyphenation-with-polyglossia), if you want both ragged left and hyphenation, you can use:

```
\leftskip=0em plus 2em
```

Comment: That changes the location of the word "anything", which I don't want.  Additionally, I _do_ want the hyphenation.  Is there a way to `\flushright` without messing up `\leftskip`, ie. right-align everything without changing other parameters?

Comment: Well, in a `\flushright` environment, all text is aligned at the right, and the left border is allowed to be ragged.  Thus, no reason for hyphenation.  Why would you want hyphenation, and according to what criterion?

Comment: I chose `\flushright` because it would give me a right-to-left setting (ie. a line that isn't full would start on the right side of the page instead of on the left).  I want fully justified lines, so `\raggedleft` is not an option, and I want hyphenations like TeX normally does English hyphenations in justified left-to-right text.

Answer (score 1):

The command `\h` is not supposed to be used for running text.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguages{hebrew}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Arial Unicode MS}

\newcommand{\h}[1]{\RL{\texthebrew{#1}\hfil}}
\newcommand{\hangparagentry}{\hangindent-0.5em \hangafter1 \leftskip 0.8em \parindent -0.5em}

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\entry}{ m o m }{%
  \noindent{\hangparagentry{\hspace{-.5em}\textbf{#1}\hspace{0.5cm} %\hfill
  \h{\hspace{0pt}#3\IfNoValueF{#2}{ \textenglish{\scriptsize{#2}}}}}\par}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\hh}{O{}m}{%
  \begin{RTL}\begin{otherlanguage*}{hebrew}%
  #1#2\par
  \end{otherlanguage*}\end{RTL}%
}

\begin{document}


\hh[\sloppy]{דער ע֜רד-צי֜טערניש-מע֜סטער, -ס דער ע֜רד-צי֜טערניש-מע֜סטער, -ס דער
  ע֜רד-צי֜טערניש-מע֜סטער, -ס דער ע֜רד-צי֜טערניש-מע֜סטער, -ס דער
  ע֜רד-צי֜טערניש-מע֜סטער, -ס דער ע֜רד-צי֜טערניש-מע֜סטער,
 -ס דער ע֜רד-צי֜טערניש-מע֜סטער, -ס דער ע֜רד-צי֜טערניש-מע֜סטער, -ס}

\entry{earthquake meter earthquake meter earthquake meter}{דער ע֜רד-צי֜טערניש-מע֜סטער, -ס}

\hh[\sloppy]{דער ע֜רד-צי֜טערניש-מע֜סטער, -ס דער ע֜רד-צי֜טערניש-מע֜סטער, -ס דער
  ע֜רד-צי֜טערניש-מע֜סטער, -ס דער ע֜רד-צי֜טערניש-מע֜סטער, -ס דער
  ע֜רד-צי֜טערניש-מע֜סטער, -ס דער ע֜רד-צי֜טערניש-מע֜סטער, -ס דער
  ע֜רד-צי֜טערניש-מע֜סטער, -ס דער ע֜רד-צי֜טערניש-מע֜סטער, -ס}

\end{document}
```

Note `\sloppy` because otherwise one line in the paragraph would be overfull.

[image]

Comment: That answers the question as asked.  What about if I wanted to have English text in the same paragraph? Since the `RTL` environment inserts a line break before and after, it splits what I want to be one paragraph into three.

Comment: @magicker72 I suggest reading the manual of `bidi`.